# What is the difference between returning an action vs returning the whole function in Page Object?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e, pageobjects

What is the difference between returning an action vs returning the whole function in Page Object?

```
this.download = function() {
  element(by.id('modal-download-button')).click();
  return this;
};
```

VS

```
this.download = function() {
  return element(by.id('modal-download-button')).click();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, to tackle timing and syncing issues, you want to explicitly resolve a promise returned by `click()`. In this case returning the "click" promise makes sense:

```
pageObject.download().then(function () {
    // ...
});
```

---

Returning a full page object could be useful for *chaining* page object methods:

```
pageObject.download().get().verify();
```